# Why File::isDirectory works fine as a FileFilter?

Tags: java, java-8

Why *File::isDirectory* works fine as a FileFilter in the below example?

```
File[] files = new File(".").listFiles(File::isDirectory);
```

The listFiles method requires a FileFilter as a parameter

```
public File[] listFiles(FileFilter filter) {
    ...
}
```

The FileFilter is a functional interface which has one method *accept* with a File parameter

```
boolean accept(File pathname);
```

And isDirectory method from the File class has no parameters

```
public boolean isDirectory() {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make things clearer the method reference `File::isDirectory` is equivalent to the following lambda:

```
file -> file.isDirectory()
```

As you can see *we're passing a `File` parameter* then calling `isDirectory` upon it which returns `boolean` hence satisfies the SAM in the `FileFilter` interface.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Because FileFilter is a `@FunctionalInterface`. It has only one method in it which takes a file as argument and returns a boolean.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FileFilter {

    /**
     * Tests whether or not the specified abstract pathname should be
     * included in a pathname list.
     *
     * @param  pathname  The abstract pathname to be tested
     * @return  <code>true</code> if and only if <code>pathname</code>
     *          should be included
     */
    boolean accept(File pathname);
}
```

If you were to expand this method reference and write it using Anonymous class. it would look like this

```
File[] files = new File(".").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
      @Override
      public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory();
      }
});
```

Which is self explanatory. Hope it is clear.

Comment: I've got it now, Thanks!