# How to create a function that takes print method reference as argument?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to create a method that takes print method reference as argument. Is there any way to create a method like below?

```
public static void main(String [] args) { 
    runFunction(System.out::print);   
}

public static void runFunction(MethodRef methodRef){
    methodRef("test");
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have created a functional interface like;

```
public interface Generatable<T> {
    void generate(T t);
}
```

And I updated my runFunction as;

```
public static void acceptFunction(Generatable generatable){
    generatable.generate("test");
}
```

this method works perfectly but I still don't get how it works. I mean how it calls print method when I call generate("test").

Comment: For this to work your MethoRef should be a function interface

Comment: @pvpkiran functional interface works perfectly. But I still don't get how it works.

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877325/why-fileisdirectory-works-fine-as-a-filefilter/50877359#50877359

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, like Prashant said.
But if you use a functional interface you better add a generic type like that:

```
public static void runFunction(Consumer<String> consumer){
    consumer.accept("test");
}
```

For more functional interfaces you can take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a `Consumer` as:

```
public static void runFunction(Consumer consumer){
    consumer.accept("test");
}
```

Side note: Functional programming is only supported with `Java 8 +`. So if you are using any version of `Java` below 8, this will not work and there is no simple way of fulfilling your requirement.